# Gettingn Oracle error PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to stored procedure, and can't find where

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, plsql, hibernate-entitymanager

I am new to Oracle and I am using Spring and Hibernate. I am trying to call a stored procedure from Oracle and execute it, but I am getting an error in my logs that haven't pinpointed me to where in the SQL query things are wrong. Additionally, I am not allowed to edit the SQL.

The procedure:

```
procedure STORED_PROCEDURE
     ( first in varchar2
     , second in varchar2
     , third in varchar2
     , fourth inout varchar2
     , fifth inout varchar2
     , sixth in boolean
     );
```

This is the code that accessed the stored procedure. It holds 4 IN parameters and 2 INOUT parameters. Three variables I hardcode into the `setParameter` pieces (fourth, fifth, and sixth). The error occurs on the `execute`.

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("STORED_PROCEDURE")
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("first", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("second", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("third", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("fourth", String.class, ParameterMode.INOUT)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("fifth", String.class, ParameterMode.INOUT)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("sixth", Boolean.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .setParameter("first", var1)
    .setParameter("second", var2)
    .setParameter("third", var3)
    .setParameter("fourth", "value")
    .setParameter("fifth", "value")
    .setParameter("sixth", true);

query.execute();
```

The full error:

```
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'STORED_PROCEDURE'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I have tried changing the Boolean parameter to `Integer.class`, because I read that there may be an issue with SQL and boolean values, and nothing worked.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using Boolean parameters for stored procedures. I suspect your issue can only be solved by better knowledge of your Spring/Hibernate API, which Oracle professionals would not know about.

Comment: You sometimes needs to match the data dictionary case for the parameter names; is it any happier if you change `"first"` to `"FIRST"` etc., both to register and set the values?

Comment: So the variable names I just switched for privacy. But, I understand what you are saying.

Comment: Update: the solution was found! Its close to what was suggested to me, but the solution for me was to use a `CallableStatement` from a connection that came from the `entityManager`, and set the statement with `setObject`, with the type as `OracleTypes.PLSQL_BOOLEAN`.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, there is no `BOOLEAN` data type in SQL but there is a `BOOLEAN` data-type in PL/SQL. This means that if you declare the procedure as:

```sql
procedure STORED_PROCEDURE
     ( first  in     varchar2
     , second in     varchar2
     , third  in     varchar2
     , fourth in out varchar2
     , fifth  in out varchar2
     , sixth  in     boolean
     );
```

Then it can only be called from a PL/SQL scope and not from SQL.

You probably want to change to using data types that are supported in both SQL and PL/SQL and define the procedure as:

```sql
procedure STORED_PROCEDURE
     ( first  in     varchar2
     , second in     varchar2
     , third  in     varchar2
     , fourth in out varchar2
     , fifth  in out varchar2
     , sixth  in     number
     );
```

Then, internally to the procedure you can convert `sixth` from a `0`/`1` value to boolean `FALSE`/`TRUE` values.

Comment: That would be a lovely fix, however sadly I do not think I am allowed to alter the SQL procedure itself...

Comment: @clocke3 Alternatively, write a second procedure that acts as a wrapper to the first procedure and does nothing except converts the 6th parameter from a number to a boolean then calls the first procedure and returns the values.

Comment: When can you call a procedure (not function) from SQL?

Comment: @AlexPoole The OP has not given details of their driver (i.e. JDBC, etc.) but commonly the Oracle drivers only implement and support SQL data types and not PL/SQL data types (like `BOOLEAN`) so all the calls are done using procedures/functions/types that are supported in the SQL scope. (One aside is that C# is an odd-ball in that its drivers support PL/SQL associative arrays but do not support SQL collections - but the Java drivers aren't like that.)

Comment: I am using the oracle.jdbc driver